# Proving a type inequality to GHC

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, gadt, type-families, singleton-type

For educational purposes, I have been trying to reconstruct an example from the book "Type-Driven Development with Idris" (namely [RemoveElem.idr](https://github.com/edwinb/TypeDD-Samples/blob/master/Chapter9/RemoveElem.idr)) in Haskell via use of various language extensions and singleton types. The gist of it is a function that removes an element from a non-empty vector, given a proof that the element is in fact in the vector. The following code is self-contained (GHC 8.4 or later). The problem appears at the very end:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}

import Data.Kind
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Void

-- | Inductively defined natural numbers.
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Eq, Show)

-- | Singleton types for natural numbers.
data SNat :: Nat -> Type where
    SZ :: SNat 'Z
    SS :: SNat n -> SNat ('S n)

deriving instance Show (SNat n)

-- | "Demote" a singleton-typed natural number to an ordinary 'Nat'.
fromSNat :: SNat n -> Nat
fromSNat SZ = Z
fromSNat (SS n) = S (fromSNat n)

-- | A decidable proposition.
data Dec a = Yes a | No (a -> Void)

-- | Propositional equality of natural numbers.
eqSNat :: SNat a -> SNat b -> Dec (a :~: b)
eqSNat  SZ     SZ    = Yes Refl
eqSNat  SZ    (SS _) = No (\case {})
eqSNat (SS _)  SZ    = No (\case {})
eqSNat (SS a) (SS b) = case eqSNat a b of
    No  f    -> No (\case Refl -> f Refl)
    Yes Refl -> Yes Refl

-- | A length-indexed list (aka vector).
data Vect :: Nat -> Type -> Type where
    Nil   :: Vect 'Z a
    (:::) :: a -> Vect n a -> Vect ('S n) a

infixr 5 :::

deriving instance Show a => Show (Vect n a)

-- | @Elem a v@ is the proposition that an element of type @a@
-- is contained in a vector of type @v@. To be useful, @a@ and @v@
-- need to refer to singleton types.
data Elem :: forall a n. a -> Vect n a -> Type where
    Here  :: Elem x (x '::: xs)
    There :: Elem x xs -> Elem x (y '::: xs)

deriving instance Show a => Show (Elem a v)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- From here on, to simplify things, only vectors of natural
-- numbers are considered.

-- | Singleton types for vectors of 'Nat's.
data SNatVect :: forall n. Nat -> Vect n Nat -> Type where
    SNatNil  :: SNatVect 'Z 'Nil
    SNatCons :: SNat a -> SNatVect n v -> SNatVect ('S n) (a '::: v)

deriving instance Show (SNatVect n v)

-- | "Demote" a singleton-typed vector of 'SNat's to an
-- ordinary vector of 'Nat's.
fromSNatVect :: SNatVect n v -> Vect n Nat
fromSNatVect SNatNil = Nil
fromSNatVect (SNatCons a v) = fromSNat a ::: fromSNatVect v

-- | Decide whether a value is in a vector.
isElem :: SNat a -> SNatVect n v -> Dec (Elem a v)
isElem _  SNatNil        = No (\case {})
isElem a (SNatCons b as) = case eqSNat a b of
    Yes Refl   -> Yes Here
    No notHere -> case isElem a as of
        Yes there   -> Yes (There there)
        No notThere -> No $ \case
            Here        -> notHere Refl
            There there -> notThere there

type family RemoveElem (a :: Nat) (v :: Vect ('S n) Nat) :: Vect n Nat where
    RemoveElem a (a '::: as) = as
    RemoveElem a (b '::: as) = b '::: RemoveElem a as

-- | Remove a (singleton-typed) element from a (non-empty, singleton-typed)
-- vector, given a proof that the element is in the vector.
removeElem :: forall (a :: Nat) (v :: Vect ('S n) Nat)
    . SNat a
    -> Elem a v
    -> SNatVect ('S n) v
    -> SNatVect n (RemoveElem a v)
removeElem x prf (SNatCons y ys) = case prf of
    Here        -> ys
    There later -> case ys of
        SNatNil    -> case later of {}
        SNatCons{} -> SNatCons y (removeElem x later ys)
            -- ^ Could not deduce:
            --            RemoveElem a (y '::: (a2 '::: v2))
            --          ~ (y '::: RemoveElem a (a2 '::: v2))
```

Apparently, the type system needs convincing that the types of the values `x` and `y` cannot possibly be equal in that branch of the code, so that the second equation of the type family can be used unambiguously to reduce the return type as required. I don't know how to do that. Naively, I would like the constructor `There` and thus the pattern match on `There later` to carry / reveal a proof of the type inequality to GHC.

The following is an obviously redundant and partial solution that just demonstrates the type inequality that is needed in order for GHC to type-check the recursive call:

```
        SNatCons{} -> case (x, y) of
            (SZ, SS _) -> SNatCons y (removeElem x later ys)
            (SS _, SZ) -> SNatCons y (removeElem x later ys)
```

Now e.g. this works:

```
λ> let vec = SNatCons SZ (SNatCons (SS SZ) (SNatCons SZ SNatNil))
λ> :t vec
vec
  :: SNatVect ('S ('S ('S 'Z))) ('Z '::: ('S 'Z '::: ('Z '::: 'Nil)))
λ> let Yes prf = isElem (SS SZ) vec
λ> :t prf
prf :: Elem ('S 'Z) ('Z '::: ('S 'Z '::: ('Z '::: 'Nil)))
λ> let vec' = removeElem (SS SZ) prf vec
λ> :t vec'
vec' :: SNatVect ('S ('S 'Z)) ('Z '::: ('Z '::: 'Nil))
λ> fromSNatVect vec'
Z ::: (Z ::: Nil)
```

## Resolution

As hinted at in @chi's comment and elaborated in [HTNW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936975/179702), I was trying to solve the wrong problem by writing `removeElem` with the above type signature and type family, and if I would have been able to, the resulting program would have been ill-typed.

The following are the corrections I made based on HTNW's answer (you may want to read it before continuing here).

The first mistake, or unnecessary complication, was to repeat the length of the vector in `SNatVect`s type. I thought it necessary in order to write `fromSNatVect`, but it certainly isn't:

```
data SNatVect (v :: Vect n Nat) :: Type where
    SNatNil  :: SNatVect 'Nil
    SNatCons :: SNat a -> SNatVect v -> SNatVect (a '::: v)

deriving instance Show (SNatVect v)

fromSNatVect :: forall (v :: Vect n Nat). SNatVect v -> Vect n Nat
-- implementation unchanged
```

Now there are two approaches to writing `removeElem`. The first takes an `Elem`, an `SNatVect` and returns a `Vect`:

```
removeElem :: forall (a :: Nat) (n :: Nat) (v :: Vect ('S n) Nat)
    . Elem a v
    -> SNatVect v
    -> Vect n Nat
removeElem prf (SNatCons y ys) = case prf of
    Here        -> fromSNatVect ys
    There later -> case ys of
        SNatNil    -> case later of {}
        SNatCons{} -> fromSNat y ::: removeElem later ys
```

The second takes an `SElem`, an `SNatVect` and returns an `SNatVect`, using a `RemoveElem` type family that mirrors the value-level function:

```
data SElem (e :: Elem a (v :: Vect n k)) where
    SHere  :: forall x xs. SElem ('Here :: Elem x (x '::: xs))
    SThere :: forall x y xs (e :: Elem x xs). SElem e -> SElem ('There e :: Elem x (y '::: xs))

type family RemoveElem (xs :: Vect ('S n) a) (e :: Elem x xs) :: Vect n a where
    RemoveElem (x '::: xs) 'Here = xs
    RemoveElem (x '::: xs) ('There later) = x '::: RemoveElem xs later

sRemoveElem :: forall (xs :: Vect ('S n) Nat) (e :: Elem x xs)
    . SElem e
    -> SNatVect xs
    -> SNatVect (RemoveElem xs e)
sRemoveElem prf (SNatCons y ys) = case prf of
    SHere        -> ys
    SThere later -> case ys of
        SNatNil    -> case later of {}
        SNatCons{} -> SNatCons y (sRemoveElem later ys)
```

Interestingly, both versions do away with passing the element to remove as a separate argument, since that information is contained in the `Elem` / `SElem` value. The `value` argument can also be removed from the Idris version of that function, though then the [removeElem_auto](https://github.com/edwinb/TypeDD-Samples/blob/master/Chapter9/RemoveElem.idr#L20) variant may be a bit confusing, as it will then only have the vector as an explicit argument and remove the first element of the vector if the implicit `prf` argument is not explicitly used with a different proof.

Comment: I wonder if `removeElem`'s type is correct. The type family `RemoveElem` removes the first occurrence, but the `prf :: Elem a v` argument could point to a different occurrence, as far as I can see. `removeElem` removes the occurrence pointed to by `prf`, so the resulting type could be different. Am I wrong?

Comment: @chi that's right. In general, the type level function must closely mirror the value level one, which is not the case here.

Comment: I'm not sure yet what problem you're seeing, but I added some information to the end of the post that may be of use.

Comment: "To be useful, `a` and `v` need to refer to singleton types"? What does that mean? If anything, `a` and `v` have 0 values, because they don't have type `Type` (and even that's a stretch, because asking how many values a type has is a question that really only makes sense in `Type`).

Comment: @HTNW Good point, that may be a poor choice of words. I just wanted to express that a type like `Elem Int (Int '::: 'Nil)` is not meaningful in Haskell where types are not values, as compared to e.g. Idris where `Elem Int (Int :: Nil)` refers to the `Int` type as the first value in a vector of types. I.e. `Elem` is only useful when it describes a relationship between two values. How would you have phrased it? Maybe something like "To be useful, `a` and `v` must be indices of singleton types."?

Comment: `Elem Int (Int ::: Nil)` is perfectly meaningful. You can e.g. define `data HList :: Vect n Type -> Type where { HNil :: HList Nil; HCons :: t -> HList ts -> HList (t ::: ts) }` (I recommend unsized lists, however), write `indexH :: forall (t :: Type) (ts :: Vect n Type). Elem t ts -> HList ts -> t`, and then `indexH @_ @Int @(Int ::: Nil) (Here :: Elem Int (Int ::: Nil)) (HCons 5 HNil :: HList (Int ::: Nil)) :: Int`. You were trying to say “There need to be singletons for `a` and `v` for `Elem a v` to be useful.” but that is simply false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider `[1, 2, 1]`. `RemoveElem 1 [1, 2, 1]` is `[2, 1]`. Now, the call `removeElem 1 (There $ There $ Here) ([1, 2, 1]  :: SNatVect 3 [1, 2, 1]) :: SNatVect 2 [2, 1]`, should compile. This is wrong. The `Elem` argument says to delete the third element, which would give `[1, 2]`, but the type signature says it must be a `[2, 1]`.

First, `SNatVect` is a bit broken. It has two `Nat` arguments:

```
data SNatVect :: forall n. Nat -> Vect n a -> Type where ...
```

The first is `n`, and the second is the unnamed `Nat`. By the structure of `SNatVect`, they are always equal. It allows an `SNatVect` to double as an equality proof, but it's probably not the intention to have it that way. You probably meant

```
data SNatVect (n :: Nat) :: Vect n Nat -> Type where ...
```

There is no way to write this signature in source Haskell using just the normal `->` syntax. However, when GHC prints this type, you sometimes get

```
SNatVect :: forall (n :: Nat) -> Vect n Nat -> Type
```

But this is redundant. You can take the `Nat` as an implicit `forall` argument, and have it inferred from the `Vect`s type:

```
data SNatVect (xs :: Vect n Nat) where
  SNatNil  :: SNatVect 'Nil
  SNatCons :: SNat x -> SNatVect xs -> SNatVect (x '::: xs)
```

This gives

```
SNatVect :: forall (n :: Nat). Vect n Nat -> Type
```

Second, try writing

```
removeElem :: forall (n :: Nat) (x :: Nat) (xs :: Vect (S n) Nat).
              Elem x xs -> SNatVect xs -> Vect n Nat
```

Note how the `SNat` argument is gone, and how the return type is a simple `Vect`. The `SNat` argument made the type "too big", so you got caught up making it sort of work when the function just wouldn't make sense. The `SNatVect` return type meant you were skipping steps. Roughly, every function has three forms: the basic one, `f :: a -> b -> c`; the type-level one, `type family F (x :: a) (y :: b) :: c`; and the dependent one, `f :: forall (x :: a) (y :: b). Sing x -> Sing y -> Sing (F x y)`. Each is implemented in the "same" way, but trying to implement one without implementing its predecessors is a surefire way to get confused.

Now, you can lift this up a little bit:

```
data SElem (e :: Elem x (xs :: Vect n k)) where
  SHere :: forall x xs. SElem ('Here :: Elem x (x '::: xs))
  SThere :: forall x y xs (e :: Elem x xs). SElem e -> SElem ('There e :: Elem x (y '::: xs))

type family RemoveElem (xs :: Vect (S n) a) (e :: Elem x xs) :: Vect n a
```

Take note of the relationship between the types of `removeElem` and `RemoveElem`. The reordering of the arguments is because the type of `e` depends on `xs`, so they need to be ordered accordingly. Alternatively: the `xs` argument was promoted from `forall`'d-and-implicitly-given to explicitly-given, and then the `Sing xs` argument was nixed because it contained no information, due to being a singleton.

Finally, you can write this function:

```
sRemoveElem :: forall (xs :: Vect (S n) Nat) (e :: Elem x xs).
               SElem e -> SNatVect xs -> SNatVect (RemoveElem xs e)
```

Comment: "Consider [1, 2, 1]. [..] The Elem argument says to delete the third element, which would give [1, 2], but the type signature says it must be a [2, 1]."

Thanks, now I also understand @chi's comment. Though such an `Elem` can not be obtained from `isElem`, this is certainly undesirable.